# Get Values from one google sheet enter it onto another sheet with a 4 loop

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have to spreadsheets.  I want the program to look at Row A on spreadsheet Ind and see if it is a 1 or 0.  if it is a one on the active sheet "return" I want it to grab the date from Row D in spreadsheet "Ind" and post it onto Spreadhseet "return".  I can't figure this out and I have it working on VBA in excel.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function myFunction() {

 X = 5;
 Y = 2;
 Z = 1;
 Count = 4560;
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Ind");
 var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Returns");

 while (Z < Count){

   if (source_sheet.getRange("A" & X) = 1) { 
      var buydate = source_sheeet.getRange("D" & X).getValues()
      target_sheet.getRange("A" & Y) = buydate
      target_sheet.getRange("B" & Y) = "Buy"
      Y = Y + 1
   } else if (source_sheeet.Range("C" & X) = 2) {
      var selldate = source_sheeet.Range("D" & X).getvalues()
      target_sheet.getRange("A" & Y) = selldate
       target_sheet.getRange("B" & Y) = "Sell"
       Y = Y + 1
   }

    X = X + 1
   Z = Z + 1
  }}
```

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` is truthy. `===` is true. You are testing things with assignment. You may also want to know that `Z = Z + 1` is the same as `Z++`, which could be put directly into your `while` loop in this case, like: `while(Z++ < Count){}`. Additionally, although not  a necessity, variable and function names are lower case to start with, camel casing each addition word like `myFunction`; whereas, Constructors and Objects are usually capitalized.

Comment: I am getting now "Range not found (line 13, file "").. I think I am having trouble understanding how to reference specific cells within a spreadsheet.

Comment: This function would run well in the debugger.  [Apps Script Troubleshooting Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)

Comment: For debugging purposes, I'd change the `Count = 4560;` to `var Count = 2;`  There's no point in looping thousands of times for code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
if (source_sheet.getRange("A" & X) = 1) {
```

Is using an ampersand, and it should be a plus sign.  To concatenate strings in JavaScript, use a plus sign.

Also, `source_sheet.getRange()` will return a range, not a value, so it's never going to equal 1. You would need to use something like the following:

```
if (source_sheet.getRange("A" + X.toString()).getValue() === 1) {
```

And use triple equal signs for an equality check.  JavaScript is constantly attempting to coerce variables into the type that seems correct.  So, it might convert the number in the variable "X" to a string, but you can also use the `toString()` method.

`getValues()` returns a two-dimensional array.  Each inner array represent a row.  Each element in the inner array represents a cell in a row.

If you only want to get one value, use `getValue()` (no "s" on the end) instead of `getValues()`.

```
var buydate = source_sheet.getRange("D" + X.toString()).getValue();
```

You are trying to set the value by using an equal sign.  That won't work.  You need to use the `setValue()` or `setValues()` method.

```
target_sheet.getRange("A" + Y.toString()).setValue(buydate);
```

By not using the `var` key word in your assignments, the variables automatically become "global" variables.

```
X = 5;
Y = 2;
Z = 1;
```

There's no need to make them global variables in this case, I don't think.

```
var X = 5,
    Y = 2,
    Z = 1;
```

You can declare multiple variables all at the same time.

Comment: Awesome this is super helpful!!! But my script doesnt stop running below is the code  
i added this to teh code
if (source_sheet.getRange("A" + X.toString()).getValues() === 1) {

Comment: `getValues()` with an "s" on the end, gets a two dimensional array.  Use `getValue()` (no "s" on the end)  That will get just one value, no array.  Use the debugger, and step through the code line by line.

Comment: Great debugging idea.  My last question is does the code target_sheet.getRange("A" + Y.toString()).setValue(selldate);  work to get the data into the cell?  I run the program and it runs fine but none of the data gets into the cells?

oh and thank you !

Comment: If no value is getting into the cell, then I'd check the value of `selldate`.  Use a `Logger.log('selldate: ' + selldate);` statement right after the line that sets the `selldate`, run the code, then in the **VIEW** menu, open the **LOGS**.  You need to become familiar with the documentation.  That will give you the answers.  [Google Documentation - Set Value](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object))